# Not able to set IP_TTLand IP_TOS Setsockopt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, setsockopt

I have defined an UDP socket

```
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h> 
sockaddr_in faraddr; 
        memset(&faraddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        unsigned short Port = 6789;
        faraddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        faraddr.sin_port        = htons(Port);
        faraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Loopbackaddress);
        SOCKET XmitSocket;
        XmitSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
          if (XmitSocket < 0)
          {
              printf("Socket Creation Failed\n");
          }
    int nBuffersize = 1024 * 1024;
    uint8 nOptVal = 255;
  setsockopt(XmitSocket,IPPROTO_IP,IP_TTL, (const char*)&nOptVal, 1);
```

//   **Identifier IP_TTL undefined**

```
    setsockopt(XmitSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF, (const char*)&nBuffersize, 4);

    int prio = 6 << 5;//First 3 bits of TOS field
    setsockopt(XmitSocket, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, &prio, sizeof(prio));
```

//   **Identifier SOL_IP and IP_TOS undefined**

I am getting compilation error Am I missing some HeaderFile

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
```

It seems that you missed some header files. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for detail.